# Magento 2.3: Mass Action For Status Not Working

Tags: magento2.3, xml, controllers, massaction, status

I'm very new to `Magento 2.3`, i created a Mass Action for Status Change, when i open action dropdown and click `Change status` a tree menu should open with 2 options, but when i click on `Change status` page just refresh, i write this code in `/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/ui_component/ec_downloads_items.xml`

```
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>

        <massaction name="listing_massaction">

        <action name="delete">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="*/items/MassDelete"/>
                <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        </action>

        <action name="status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change status</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="actions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="*/items/MassStatus">
                    <param name="status">1</param>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disable</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="*/items/MassStatus">
                    <param name="status">2</param>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        </action>

        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
```

and this code in `/EC/Downloads/Controller/Adminhtml/Items/MassStatus.php`

```
<?php
namespace EC\Downloads\Controller\Adminhtml\Items;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use EC\Downloads\Model\ResourceModel\Items\CollectionFactory; // Define your collection here
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Class MassDisable
 */
class MassStatus extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;


    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, Filter $filter, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Execute action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
    echo 'Hello';exit;
        $statusValue = $this->getRequest()->getParam('status');
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $item->setStatus($statusValue);
            $item->save();
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been modified.', $collection->getSize()));

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

code in `/EC/Downloads/Model/ResourceModel/Items.php`

```
<?php

namespace EC\Downloads\Model\ResourceModel;
/**
 * Class Items
 * @package EC\Downloads\Model\ResourceModel
 */
class Items extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    /**
     *
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('downloads', 'downloads_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the component in `<massaction>` tag:

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
     .........
</massaction>
```